# Creating a magic item with two continuous effects I can pick between (or deactivate)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

I was working on a magic item belt in Pathfinder. The belt is going to provide the standard boosts to Str/Dex/Con.

However, I also want it to have a split property, and I'm struggling with how to pull it off: I want it to give me a continuous activation of reduce person *or* enlarge person *or* for neither one to be active.

It's simple to just add both enlarge and reduce to the belt as continuous costs, but that doesn't give me the effect I want. At the same point in time I can't just say that one effect is happening but not the other one. I don't want to go the route of x-activations.

Is there some way to work an activation and deactivation into the continuous item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. An item which is usable at-will is *almost* as good as a continuous effect for many users.
2. If the item can be made with a conditional requirement for activation (e.g. when the switch is in the 'Large' position) as per [intermittent functioning for cursed items](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/cursed-items#TOC-Intermittent_Functioning), this is trivial.  Unfortunately no rules for price or prerequisite modification exist, which deters some GMs from allowing this powerful subsystem in play.
3. If you're allowed to break Wealth By Level guidelines (WBL), you can buy 2-3 belts and swap 'em as needed.

   - You can use additional magics (e.g. mage hand, swift girding, animate rope) to rotate between them handlessly and with ease.  The three belts can then be themselves placed within a non-magical (I'm thinking woven lead) sleeve so as to form one cohesive item from the perspective of onlookers while remaining three items from the perspective of the world.
4. The most common rulings by far on what happens if you wear more magic items than you have slots is that none of the items of the type of slot you've exceeded function.  The second most common ruling, in my experience, is that only the allowed number of items function, and you choose which ones are active and the others are inactive.  If this latter ruling is in effect consider just wearing *lots of belts:*

   [image: Too Many Belts!]
5. Worst comes to worst, you can do this with continual Limited Wish, or a couple other spell-copying spells, but it's stupidly expensive.  You could also use contingency in the crafting with similar problems.

Comment: What was "If you're allowed to break WBL and lame" supposed to say? I couldn't figure out the intended meaning to correct the typo.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I parse that as "If you're allowed to break WBL, and you're lame, have multiple belts." I'm just gonna edit out that bit about being lame, it sounds like an unhelpful value judgement. (Also turns out it can just be merged into the previous point.)

Comment: What does WBL mean?

Comment: @Fering Oh, it's "Wealth By Level". I see it wasn't ever explained, so I expanded that in the post.

Comment: Since I have followed the correct rules for applying multiple effects (meaning a horribly expensive belt, please no thieves!) it will be a very high level belt.

Comment: @doppelgreener Yup, seems fair enough.

Comment: @Fering If you or someone you know is a caster or a rogue and the GM doesn't find some way to curtail the fact you can generate vast quantities of wealth on a whim you won't need to be that high of a level.  Also I strongly reccomend you talk to your DM about the 'group of related powers' cost reduction, as reduce/enlarge person seem like a good pair for that modifier.  The stat boosts, obviously, aren't, though.

Comment: @the dark wanderer, the cost isnt the concern, its figuring out some way to toggle between the effects I wanted that hopefully existed already, or coming up with a new way and having a fair price.

Comment: As a counter argument for the 2nd ruling from point 4, there exists an item (conveniently a belt, meridian-belt) that allows you to wear 4 rings and switch between them, so I would argue wearing excessive items and switching is not something that would be allowed, at least easily. And if its not easy to switch, why not simply buy 2 belts and take them off and on?